# Why is actix-session not correctly assigning values?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am newbie to Rust, and I am developing a Rust HTTP API with [Actix Web](https://actix.rs/). In order to maintain the session between requests, I wanted to use the official-provided package [Actix Session](https://crates.io/crates/actix-session), currently, this is my implementation on `main.rs`:

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let session_secret_key = CookieKeyHelper::generate();

    let server = HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(Cors::permissive())
            .wrap(
                SessionMiddleware::builder(
                    CookieSessionStore::default(),
                    session_secret_key.clone(),
                )
                .cookie_secure(false)
                .build(),
            )
    // [...]
    })
```

And in some places I'm calling it:

```rust
      // [...]
          return match token_result {
            Ok(token) => {
                println!("Received token: {:?}", token);
                println!("Access token: {:?}", token.access_token().secret());
                session
                    .insert::<StandardTokenResponse<EmptyExtraTokenFields, BasicTokenType>>(
                        "token", token,
                    )
                    .unwrap();
                session
                    .insert::<AuthorizationCode>(
                        "auth_code",
                        AuthorizationCode::new(query["code"].to_string()),
                    )
                    .unwrap();
      // [...]
```

No errros are raised, but then, when I try to read the session values with `session.entries()`, it is always empty `{}`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm having the same problem. This guy said the cookie session provider isn't good and switched to Redis. I'm hoping there's a faster solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76014078/unable-to-get-user-id-from-actix-web-session-data-after-successful-login

Answer (score 0):

Using a non-random key worked for me. Not sure why though.

Replace

```rust
let session_secret_key = CookieKeyHelper::generate();
```

with

```rust
let session_secret_key = "a_really_long_random_key___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________";
```