# Unable to get user_id from Actix Web session data after successful login

Tags: rust, actix-web

EDIT:

In the original post I was using CookieSession. After reading the comment from Đorđe below, I decided to switch to using redis for session handling. Setting up redis was painless (with some help from gpt) and the sessions are now persistent.

ORIGINAL POST:

I am learning Rust and working on a project using Actix Web. I have implemented a login system and set up middleware for login authentication. When I submit the login, the user id is passed to the browser and stored in the cookie. I can maintain the user id when navigating between pages on the site. However, I am unable to retrieve the user id from the session data once logged in.

```
#[post("/login")]
async fn login_submit(
    pool: web::Data<PgPool>,
    form_data: Form<LoginFormData>,
    session: actix_session::Session,
) -> Result<impl Responder, WrappedError> {
    let user = match db::get_user_by_email(&pool, &form_data.email).await {
        Ok(user) => user,
        Err(_) => return Err(WrappedError(anyhow!("Invalid email or password"))),
    };

    let password_hash = PasswordHash::new(&user.password_hash)
        .map_err(|_| WrappedError(anyhow!("Invalid password hash")))?;

    let argon2 = Argon2::default();

    let password_verified = argon2
        .verify_password(form_data.password.as_bytes(), &password_hash)
        .is_ok();

    println!("Password verified: {}", password_verified);
    println!("Stored hashed password: {}", user.password_hash);

    if password_verified {
        session
            .insert("user_id", user.id)
            .map_err(|e| WrappedError(anyhow!("Session error: {}", e)))?;
        println!("Session set with user_id: {}", user.id);
    
        // Add these lines to print the user_id from the session after setting it
        match session.get::<i32>("user_id") {
            Ok(Some(user_id)) => println!("User id in session after setting: {}", user_id),
            Ok(None) => println!("User id not found in session after setting"),
            Err(e) => println!("Error getting user id from session after setting: {}", e),
        }
    
        let response = HttpResponse::Found().append_header(("location", "/")).finish();
        Ok(response)
    } else {
        Err(WrappedError(anyhow!("Invalid email or password")))
    }
}
```

However, when I try to access the user id in my middleware, it comes out as `None`. Here is the code for my middleware:

```
impl<S> Service<ServiceRequest> for UserLoginStatusMiddleware<S>
where
    S: Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<EitherBody<BoxBody>>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
{
    type Response = ServiceResponse<EitherBody<BoxBody>>;
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = LocalBoxFuture<'static, Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>;

    forward_ready!(service);

    fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let session = req.get_session();
        let user_id: Option<i32> = session.get("user_id").unwrap_or(None);
        let user_logged_in = user_id.is_some();

        println!("UserLoginStatusMiddleware user_id: {:?}", user_id);
        println!("UserLoginStatusMiddleware user_logged_in: {}", user_logged_in);
        println!("UserLoginStatusMiddleware session cookie: {:?}", req.cookie("my_session"));
        println!("UserLoginStatusMiddleware request headers: {:?}", req.headers());

        req.extensions_mut().insert(user_logged_in);

        let fut = self.service.call(req);
        Box::pin(async move {
            let res = fut.await?;
            Ok(res)
        })
    }
}
```

In the middleware, I try to retrieve the user id using `session.get("user_id").unwrap_or(None)`, but this doesn't seem to work. Is there something wrong with this approach, or is there an alternative way to retrieve the user id from the session?

My code compiles without errors.

I'm registering the app like this:

```
App::new()
            .wrap(
                CookieSession::signed(&[0; 32])
                    .secure(false)
                    .name("my_session")
                    .path("/")
                    .http_only(true)
            )
            .wrap(UserLoginStatus)
...
```

Comment: `session.get` returns `Result`, and documentation says `It returns an error if it fails to deserialize as T the JSON value associated with key.`. Try to print error from `session.get` to find out if you have issue with types. Type you `insert` and `get` has to be the same.

Comment: I tried this:

let user_id: Option<i32> = session.get("user_id").unwrap_or_else(|err| {
            eprintln!("Error getting user_id from session: {}", err);
            None
        });

user_id is still printed as None, but with no error. Should I interpret that as the user_id not existing in the session at all?

Comment: Yes, that means your session is not persistent. Did you check `actix` repo for examples? https://github.com/actix/actix-extras/tree/master/actix-session/examples

Comment: Maybe to re-check way you set up session storage

Comment: This was a very useful pointer. I ended up changing my code to use redis for handling sessions. Setting up redis was relatively painless, and the session handling works now.